# positioning of 2 elements within another element in CSS

Tags: css, layout, positioning

After I do a search here :http://www.zm-online.de/kleinanzeigen/anzeigen_index_18862.html, the blue box is collapsed and the white text cut off. I know it's because of the link to the right called: "zurück zur Übersicht".

I need to have the white text showing and the blue box be the full height like it was before you did the search (http://www.zm-online.de/kleinanzeigen/anzeigen_index_18862.html).

The line-height: normal; for line 7427 is not going to fix it. I need to have the blue box bigger.

Even though I know CSS I don't know it that well to understand why. So I did the following and it seemed to have worked. I would like to know if this is acceptable and why it worked. (Sorry!)

So, on line 2042, I took out float:right; and left this: 
`.blue_headline a.back {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    line-height: 16px;
}`

This seems to do the trick, but I think the blue box is still 1 or 2 pixels off.

Should I also add this? (not sure if it's necessary)

and on line 7427, I added the line-height: inherit;:
    .content_box .blue_headline h2 {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: inherit;
}

Any help is appreciated and I am sorry if I did not explain myself the correct way. I am new to this, so please have some patience with me. :-)

Thank YOU!!
Rita

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
header.blue_headline {overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow. If an answer helps you solve your problem, you should mark it as correct.

Comment: Hi Jezen, Sorry... not quite sure about the proper etiquette yet. ;-)

Comment: BTW, I also fixed it w/ overflow: hidden; because if you put in more text it will create scroll bars. So, I thought to use overflow: hidden; instead to be on the save side. Is this okay?

Comment: Yeah, that's a better solution. Updated my answer.